# Combining an INNER JOIN query with Count of different values

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I am trying to link two tables with similar column. I need to find out how many values differ from table1.column1 and table 2.column1:

My current query:

```
SELECT i10_descr.i10_code, gems_pcsi9.i10_code
FROM i10_descr INNER JOIN gems_pcsi9 ON i10_descr.i10_code = gems_pcsi9.i10_code
ORDER BY i10_descr.i10_code;
```

I know this query shows the matching codes of each table: I cannot figure out how to COUNT the missing/different codes in the tables.

Also, I have to compute the ratio of codes.

Any help, tips, or direction is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use an anti-join pattern to get a list of i10_code that exist in one table, but not the other.  For example:

```
SELECT i.i10_code
  FROM i10_descr i
  LEFT
  JOIN gems_pcsi9 g
    ON g.i10_code = i.i10_code
 WHERE g.i10_code IS NULL
 ORDER BY i.i10_code
```

If you just want a count, you could use `COUNT(i.i10_code)` and/or `COUNT(DISINCT i.i10_code)` in the SELECT list and remove the ORDER BY clause.

To get the i10_code in the gems table that aren't in the i10 table, you'd do the same thing but invert the query so that gems is the "driving" table. e.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT g.i10_code) AS cnt_diff
  FROM gems_pcsi9 g
  LEFT
  JOIN i10_descr i
    ON i.i10_code = g.i10_code
 WHERE i.i10_code IS NULL
```

If you want to combine the number of differences, you can combine the two queries by making them inline views:

```
SELECT d.cnt_diff + e.cnt_diff AS total_diff 
  FROM (
         SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT g.i10_code) AS cnt_diff
           FROM gems_pcsi9 g
            LEFT
            JOIN i10_descr i
              ON i.i10_code = g.i10_code
           WHERE i.i10_code IS NULL
       ) d
 CROSS 
  JOIN ( 
         SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT i.i10_code) AS cnt_diff
           FROM i10_descr i
           LEFT
           JOIN gems_pcsi9 g
             ON g.i10_code = i.i10_code
          WHERE g.i10_code IS NULL
       ) e
```

NOTE: the COUNT aggregate will omit NULL values. The query would need to be tweaked if you also wanted to "count" rows that had NULL values for i10_code. You'd use `COUNT(DISTINCT )` if you want just a number of distinct values that are different. A `COUNT()` would give a number of rows. These two results would be different if you had multiple rows with the same `i10_code` value.

---

To get a "ratio" of codes, assuming that at this point, the "differences" don't matter, you get a count of codes from each table. The queries to do that could be used inline views:

```
SELECT d.cnt / e.cnt AS ratio_cnt_g_over_cnt_i
     , d.cnt         AS cnt_g
     , e.cnt         AS cnt_i
  FROM (
         SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT g.i10_code) AS cnt
           FROM gems_pcsi9 g
       ) d
 CROSS 
  JOIN ( 
         SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT i.i10_code) AS cnt
           FROM i10_descr i
       ) e
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method is to use `union all` with aggregation:

```
select in_i10descr, in_gems_pcsi9, count(*) as numcodes
from (select code, max(in_i10descr) as in_i10descr, max(in_gems_pcsi9) as in_gems_pcsi9
      from ((select i10_descr.i10_code as code, 1 as in_i10descr, 0 as in_gems_pcsi9
             from i10_descr
            ) union all
            (select gems_pcsi9.i10_code, 0, 1
             gems_pcsi9.i10_code
            )
           ) t
      group by code
     ) c
group by in_i10descr, in_gems_pcsi9;
```

This will calculate counts of things in each table separately and in both tables.